# Why is 1<x<3 always true?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript, and in the getting started page, they talk about how unexpected javascript is.

**Source**: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html

```
if ("" == 0) {
// It is! But why??
}
if (1 < x < 3) {
// True for *any* value of x!
}
```

But I still don't understand why `1<x<3` is always true? For example if I let x=10, it will not be true by logic, but why they said it always true?

Comment: Change it to `1 < x && x < 3`. Also consider learning JS before typescript

Comment: Because `1 < x` is either `true` or `false`, and both `true`(1) and `false`(0) are smaller than 3 ?

Comment: @Psidom Of course you should simplify complex circumstances but please don't say _"`true` and `false` are smaller than 3"_. `true < 3` and `false < 3` are true because of very confusing conversion rules but that doesn't mean that true or false are smaller 3.

Comment: @jabaa Isn't it how it works in C ?

Comment: @Psidom No, there is no `true` or `false` in C.

Comment: @jabaa https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html

Comment: @Psidom Yes, you're right. There is a boolean library in C (didn't know about it). But `true` and `false` are just macros for numeric values. Creating a macro `NaN` with value `-1` doesn't mean that `NaN` is smaller 3 in JavaScript. `true` or `false` are either aliases for numeric values (e.g. in C) or they are converted to numeric values. But  IMHO it's wrong to say: Boolean `true` is smaller than `3`. The value `0` is falsy but not false

Comment: @Psidom The accepted answer contains a similar sentence with an important difference: _"`false` becomes `0` or `true` becomes `1`, and both `0` and `1` always less than `3`."_

Comment: @jabaa Sure, semantically `true` and `false` are different from `1` and `0`. But `true == 1` and `false == 0` are correct in many languages, same goes with comparisons.

Comment: @Psidom But `false === 0` is false in JavaScript. This is a JavaScript question. `false` is not a number and booleans don't have an ordering.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1 < x < 3` actually is doing this:

```
(1 < x) < 3
```

Or even more long form:

```
const tempVarA = 1 < x
const tempVarB = tempVarA < 3
```

So `1 < x` is either `true` or `false`. Then the next step is `true < 3` or `false < 3`. Those don't make much sense as comparisons, but let's see what javascript does with that:

```
console.log(true < 3) // true
console.log(false < 3) // true
```

Weird, but let's dig deeper:

```
console.log(true >= 0) // true
console.log(true >= 1) // true
console.log(true >= 2) // false

console.log(false >= 0) // true
console.log(false >= 1) // false
console.log(false >= 2) // false
```

It seems that `true` is being treated as `1` and `false` is being treated as `0`. To verify that let's compare with `==` (instead of `===`) so that it coerces the type of the data for us.

```
console.log(true == 1) // true
console.log(true == 0) // false
console.log(false == 1) // false
console.log(false == 0) // true
```

So `1 < x < 3` is always true because false becomes `0` or true becomes `1`, and both `0` and `1` always less than `3`.

---

### Explanation:

in javascript, comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, and `!=` coerce their operands to make them comparable when they are different types. So when comparing a boolean to a number it coverts the boolean to a number, `0` or `1`.

This is why you should almost *always* use `===` instead of `==`, and why this is a type error in typescript:

```
const a = true < 3
// Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.(2365)
```

---

### Short version

Javascript and typescript lack a chainable comparison operator.

Did you mean to do this?

```
1 < x && x < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

in other words: true is 1 and false is 0. Therefore 1 < x < 3 with x = 5 is as if it executes (1 <5) <3 and writes to 1 <5 = 1 (true) and then 1 <3 = 1 (true). If instead x were 0? Ok 1 <0 is false (0) consequently 0 <3 is true (1)